# Bash script check if zip file is empty

Tags: linux, bash

I am rather inexperienced in linux,
I have to check in bash script if some zip file is empty - i.e zip contains no files.
I found this code:

```
if ! zipinfo ${filetotransfer} | tail -n 1 | grep '^0 ' >/dev/null ; then # we have empty zip file!
   echo " zip empty"
   rm $filetotransfer
   exit 0
fi
```

But it removes file both if zip is empty or not.
Is there any way to check it?

Comment: Have you tested that your conditional works as expected?  What is the output of `zipinfo ${filetotransfer} | tail -n 1 | grep '^0 '`? How about the return code?  Are they what you expect?

Comment: I tested it: it removes file in all cases.

Comment: That does not, in fact, answer either of the two specific questions I asked.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can just check file size is 22 with stat or md5sum or zip header

```
# by checking file size
% stat -f%z a.zip 
22

% xxd a.zip
0000000: 504b 0506 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  PK..............
0000010: 0000 0000 0000                           ......

# with md5sum
$ md5sum a.zip
76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c  a.zip

# or by checking zip header
% [ `head -n22 a.zip | tr -d '\0-\6'` = "PK" ] && echo 1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error status of `zipinfo -t`

```
f=test.zip
if zipinfo -t "$f" > /dev/null
then
    echo "not empy"
else
    echo "empty"
fi
```